# Error: Section 7 has invalid sh_entsize 0

Tags: gcc, arm, u-boot, binutils

### Compiling U-boot for ARM

I am compiling U-boot for ARM target using GCC and the U-boot build successfully.
The u-boot is configured for am335x_evm(sitara) target board as:

```
export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi-
make k2hk_evm_config
make u-boot
```

But when i try to read the Uboot ELF using readelf utility then i am seeing error as:

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-readelf -S u-boot
```

There are 27 section headers, starting at offset 0x1aadb4:

> readelf: **Error: Section 7 has invalid sh_entsize 0 (expected 8)**

Comment: `readelfarm`, why not `arm-linux-gnueabi-readelf`?

Comment: it's arm-linux-gnueabi-readelf only.

Comment: What if check all object file, to find out bad one, for example like this `find . -name "*.o" -exec /bin/sh -c "readelf -S {} > /dev/null || echo "bad object " {}" \;` ?

Comment: I am not seeing any object file with "bad object" after running the above mentioned command.
Getting NULL output

Comment: But here if i try to read the relocation  entries in the binary as:

**arm-linux-gnueabi-readelf --relocs u-boot**

Then here i am seeing many bad entries into it as:

`0c03fdb0  0c0021c0 unrecognized: c0      bad symbol index: 000c0021

0c03fdb4  0c002184 unrecognized: 84      bad symbol index: 000c0021

0c03fdb4  0c0020d0 unrecognized: d0      bad symbol index: 000c0020
0c047e08  0c003ef8 unrecognized: f8      bad symbol index: 000c003e
0c04a808  0c00138c unrecognized: 8c      bad symbol index: 000c0013`